# InfoPath and Dynamics AX

Tags: infopath, active-directory, service-account

I have an InfoPath 2010 form that I am publishing to SharePoint 2013. I have added rules like PreferredName, WorkEmail and WorkPhone to auto populate and everything works fine when I preview. The challenge I have now is that we have dynamics AX in our environment and when I publish this InfoPath to SharePoint it populates svc-axadmin as the PreferredName instead of the current user preferred name from AD. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you create the "PreferredName" rule? Did you follow [these](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331606/How-to-set-Current-User-Name-to-InfoPath-Person-Gr) steps?

Having Dynamics AX in your environment should NOT have any affect on how you display a preferredName in your infopath form. User information is pulled from user profile service application which in turn pulls from AD in general.

Comment: I guess there is a problem with our dev environment because when I tried the step mentioned above I got the same result but in our prod env everything worked fine. thanks ken